# Why is the request path to text.js wrong in Durandal Get started tutorial?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

I'm trying to setup a site using the Durandal [Get Started](http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/) tutorial. But the when I try to run the site I get multiple javascript error. I'm guessing these are caused by a 404 request to "App/text.js". As far as I can see, this should be "App/durandal/amd/text.js".

Anyone know if there could be a setting I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So right after asking the question I tried getting the nuget durandal starter package.
It seems that the following is missing from the tutorial:

> requirejs.config({
>       paths: {
>           'text': 'durandal/amd/text'
>       }
>   });

This should be added to the top of the main.js file.